# How can I generate pseudo random sequence of binary number using Hopefield neural network?

Tags: python, random, binary

For some work, I need to generate a sequence of random binary patterns using the Hopefield neural network.
Like I want to generate a 42-bit long binary sequence such as '11101100011100111001100011001110001010001'  How can I generate it?

I have tried several ways but no proper solution is coming out.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy to pick a random int.

Here we specifiy dtype to address up to 64 bits, and a maximum value of 2^42.

Use f-string to print the binary representation and pad with leading 0 if needed.

```py
import numpy as np

n = np.random.randint(2**42, dtype=np.int64)
print(f"{n:042b}")
```